# I wrote a C++ program that would simulate Enigma machine.I am not getting the output

Tags: c++

This program works till getting a string, after that it does not encrypt it.
 I am a beginner programmer who just started to code,kindly help me
 I suspect,the logic part of the code is not working

```
{
  void logic(int l,char a[],char b[],Rotor r1,Rotor r2,Rotor r3);
}
```

and for the cryptic text I used:https://nicerc.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Enigma-Pringles-1.pdf

Expected output:

```
Enter the three Rotor arrangements(1/2/3):1 2 3
Enter the three Rotor position:a a a
Enter the String:r
The encrypted string is:n
```

Actual output:

```
Enter the three Rotor arrangements(1/2/3):1 2 3
Enter the three Rotor position:a a a
Enter the String:r
The encrypted string is:
```

Code:

```cpp
#include<iostream>


using namespace std;
class Rotor
{
    public:
    char r[26][3];
    Rotor(int m,char ch);

};

void movement(Rotor r1,Rotor r2,Rotor r3,int l)
{
   //for rotor1
   int k,i;
   k=1;
   for(i=0;i<26;i++)
   {
       if (i==25)
       {
           r1.r[i][1]=r1.r[0][1];
       }
       else
       {
           r1.r[i][1]=r1.r[i+1-k][1];
           k=0;
       }
    //for rotor2
    if(l%26==0 && l!=0)
    {
        for(i=0;i<26;i++)
        {
            if(i==25)
            {
                r2.r[i][1]=r2.r[0][1];
            }
            else
            {
                r2.r[i][1]=r2.r[i+1][1];
            }

        }
    }
    //for rotor3
    if(l%676==0 && l!=0)
    {
        for(i=0;i<26;i++)
        {
            if(i==25)
            {
                r3.r[i][1]=r3.r[0][1];
            }
            else
            {
                r3.r[i][1]=r3.r[i+1][1];
            }

        }
    }


   }
}


void logic(int l,char a[],char b[],Rotor r1,Rotor r2,Rotor r3);

int main()
{
  int m,n,o;
  char ch1,ch2,ch3;
  cout<<"Enter the three Rotor arrangements(1/2/3):";
  cin>>m>>n>>o;
  cout<<"Enter the three Rotor position:";
  cin>>ch1>>ch2>>ch3;
  Rotor r1(m,ch1);
  Rotor r2(n,ch2);
  Rotor r3(o,ch3);
    int p;
  if(m<n && n<o)
  {
     p=1;
  }
  else if(m<o && o<n)
  {
     p=2;
  }
  else if(n<m && m<o)
  {
     p=3;
  }
  else if(n<o && o<m)
  {
     p=4;
  }
  else if(o<n && n<m)
  {
     p=5;
  }
   else if(o<m && m<n)
  {
     p=6;
  }
  char a[500],b[500];
cout<<"Enter the String:";
cin>>a;
int l;
for(l=0;a[l]!='\0';l++)
{
    if(p==1)
    {
        logic(l,a,b,r1,r2,r3);
        movement(r1,r2,r3,l);
    }
    else if(p==2)
    {
        logic(l,a,b,r1,r3,r2);
        movement(r1,r3,r2,l);
    }
     else if(p==3)
    {
        logic(l,a,b,r2,r1,r3);
        movement(r2,r1,r3,l);
    }
     else if(p==4)
    {
        logic(l,a,b,r2,r3,r1);
        movement(r2,r3,r1,l);
    }
     else if(p==5)
    {
        logic(l,a,b,r3,r2,r1);
        movement(r3,r2,r1,l);
    }
     else if(p==6)
    {
        logic(l,a,b,r3,r1,r2);
        movement(r3,r1,r2,l);
    }


}
cout<<b;



return 0;


}

Rotor::Rotor(int m,char ch)  //constructor
{
    if(m==1)
    {
      char r[26][3]=
    {
      'a','c','b','d','c','e','d','a','e','b','f','g','g','i',
      'h','f','i','h','j','l','k','j','l','m','m','o','n','k',
      'o','r','p','n','q','t','r','u','s','p','t','q','u','w',
      'v','s','w','v','x','z','y','x','z','y'
    };
    int i,j,d;
    for(i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
        if(r[i][1]==ch)
        break;
    }
    for(j=0;j<26;j++)
    {
        d=(j+i)%26;
        r[j][1]=r[d][1];
    }

    }
    else if(m==2)
    {
       char r[26][3]=
    {
     'a','b','b','a','c','d','d','e','e','f','f','c','g','i',
      'h','g','i','h','j','l','k','m','l','j','m','k','n','o',
      'o','n','p','q','q','r','r','p','s','u','t','s','u','t',
      'v','y','w','z','x','v','y','w','z','x'
    };
    int i,j,d;
    for(i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
        if(r[i][1]==ch)
        break;
    }
    for(j=0;j<26;j++)
    {
        d=(j+i)%26;
        r[j][1]=r[d][1];
    }
    }
    else if(m==3)
    {
       char r[26][3]=
    {
      'a','d','b','a','c','b','d','g','e','h','f','c','g','e',
      'h','f','i','j','j','i','k','l','l','k','m','p','n','m',
      'o','n','p','o','q','s','r','t','s','q','t','r','u','x',
      'v','y','w','z','x','u','y','v','z','w'
    };
    int i,j,d;
    for(i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
        if(r[i][1]==ch)
        break;
    }
    for(j=0;j<26;j++)
    {
        d=(j+i)%26;
        r[j][1]=r[d][1];
    }

    }
}
void logic(int l,char a[],char b[],Rotor r1,Rotor r2,Rotor r3)
{
   char temp=a[l];
   switch(temp)//Rotor 1
   {
       case 'a':
           temp=r1.r[0][1];
           break;
       case 'b':
           temp=r1.r[1][1];
           break;
       case 'c':
           temp=r1.r[2][1];
           break;
       case 'd':
           temp=r1.r[3][1];
           break;
       case 'e':
           temp=r1.r[4][1];
           break;
       case 'f':
           temp=r1.r[5][1];
           break;
       case 'g':
           temp=r1.r[6][1];
           break;
       case 'h':
           temp=r1.r[7][1];
           break;
       case 'i':
           temp=r1.r[8][1];
           break;
       case 'j':
           temp=r1.r[9][1];
           break;
       case 'k':
           temp=r1.r[10][1];
           break;
       case 'l':
           temp=r1.r[11][1];
           break;
       case 'm':
           temp=r1.r[12][1];
           break;
       case 'n':
           temp=r1.r[13][1];
           break;
       case 'o':
           temp=r1.r[14][1];
           break;
       case 'p':
           temp=r1.r[15][1];
           break;
       case 'q':
           temp=r1.r[16][1];
           break;
       case 'r':
           temp=r1.r[17][1];
           break;
       case 's':
           temp=r1.r[18][1];
           break;
       case 't':
           temp=r1.r[19][1];
           break;
       case 'u':
           temp=r1.r[20][1];
           break;
       case 'v':
           temp=r1.r[21][1];
           break;
       case 'w':
           temp=r1.r[22][1];
           break;
       case 'x':
           temp=r1.r[23][1];
           break;
       case 'y':
           temp=r1.r[24][1];
           break;
       case 'z':
           temp=r1.r[25][1];
           break;
   }
   switch(temp)//Rotor 2
   {
       case 'a':
           temp=r2.r[0][1];
           break;
       case 'b':
           temp=r2.r[1][1];
           break;
       case 'c':
           temp=r2.r[2][1];
           break;
       case 'd':
           temp=r2.r[3][1];
           break;
       case 'e':
           temp=r2.r[4][1];
           break;
       case 'f':
           temp=r2.r[5][1];
           break;
       case 'g':
           temp=r2.r[6][1];
           break;
       case 'h':
           temp=r2.r[7][1];
           break;
       case 'i':
           temp=r2.r[8][1];
           break;
       case 'j':
           temp=r2.r[9][1];
           break;
       case 'k':
           temp=r2.r[10][1];
           break;
       case 'l':
           temp=r2.r[11][1];
           break;
       case 'm':
           temp=r2.r[12][1];
           break;
       case 'n':
           temp=r2.r[13][1];
           break;
       case 'o':
           temp=r2.r[14][1];
           break;
       case 'p':
           temp=r2.r[15][1];
           break;
       case 'q':
           temp=r2.r[16][1];
           break;
       case 'r':
           temp=r2.r[17][1];
           break;
       case 's':
           temp=r2.r[18][1];
           break;
       case 't':
           temp=r2.r[19][1];
           break;
       case 'u':
           temp=r2.r[20][1];
           break;
       case 'v':
           temp=r2.r[21][1];
           break;
       case 'w':
           temp=r2.r[22][1];
           break;
       case 'x':
           temp=r2.r[23][1];
           break;
       case 'y':
           temp=r2.r[24][1];
           break;
       case 'z':
           temp=r2.r[25][1];
           break;
   }
   switch(temp)//Rotor 3
   {
       case 'a':
           temp=r3.r[0][1];
           break;
       case 'b':
           temp=r3.r[1][1];
           break;
       case 'c':
           temp=r3.r[2][1];
           break;
       case 'd':
           temp=r3.r[3][1];
           break;
       case 'e':
           temp=r3.r[4][1];
           break;
       case 'f':
           temp=r3.r[5][1];
           break;
       case 'g':
           temp=r3.r[6][1];
           break;
       case 'h':
           temp=r3.r[7][1];
           break;
       case 'i':
           temp=r3.r[8][1];
           break;
       case 'j':
           temp=r3.r[9][1];
           break;
       case 'k':
           temp=r3.r[10][1];
           break;
       case 'l':
           temp=r3.r[11][1];
           break;
       case 'm':
           temp=r3.r[12][1];
           break;
       case 'n':
           temp=r3.r[13][1];
           break;
       case 'o':
           temp=r3.r[14][1];
           break;
       case 'p':
           temp=r3.r[15][1];
           break;
       case 'q':
           temp=r3.r[16][1];
           break;
       case 'r':
           temp=r3.r[17][1];
           break;
       case 's':
           temp=r3.r[18][1];
           break;
       case 't':
           temp=r3.r[19][1];
           break;
       case 'u':
           temp=r3.r[20][1];
           break;
       case 'v':
           temp=r3.r[21][1];
           break;
       case 'w':
           temp=r3.r[22][1];
           break;
       case 'x':
           temp=r3.r[23][1];
           break;
       case 'y':
           temp=r3.r[24][1];
           break;
       case 'z':
           temp=r3.r[25][1];
           break;
   }
   //REFLECTOR
   switch(temp)
   {

       case 'a':
           temp='e';
           break;
       case 'b':
           temp='d';
           break;
       case 'c':
           temp='h';
           break;
       case 'd':
           temp='b';
           break;
       case 'e':
           temp='a';
           break;
       case 'f':
           temp='i';
           break;
       case 'g':
           temp='l';
           break;
       case 'h':
           temp='c';
           break;
       case 'i':
           temp='f';
           break;
       case 'j':
           temp='m';
           break;
       case 'k':
           temp='o';
           break;
       case 'l':
           temp='g';
           break;
       case 'm':
           temp='j';
           break;
       case 'n':
           temp='s';
           break;
       case 'o':
           temp='k';
           break;
       case 'p':
           temp='r';
           break;
       case 'q':
           temp='u';
           break;
       case 'r':
           temp='p';
           break;
       case 's':
           temp='n';
           break;
       case 't':
           temp='w';
           break;
       case 'u':
           temp='q';
           break;
       case 'v':
           temp='y';
           break;
       case 'w':
           temp='t';
           break;
       case 'x':
           temp='z';
           break;
       case 'y':
           temp='v';
           break;
       case 'z':
           temp='x';
           break;
   }
    switch(temp)//Rotor 3
   {
       case 'a':
           temp=r3.r[0][1];
           break;
       case 'b':
           temp=r3.r[1][1];
           break;
       case 'c':
           temp=r3.r[2][1];
           break;
       case 'd':
           temp=r3.r[3][1];
           break;
       case 'e':
           temp=r3.r[4][1];
           break;
       case 'f':
           temp=r3.r[5][1];
           break;
       case 'g':
           temp=r3.r[6][1];
           break;
       case 'h':
           temp=r3.r[7][1];
           break;
       case 'i':
           temp=r3.r[8][1];
           break;
       case 'j':
           temp=r3.r[9][1];
           break;
       case 'k':
           temp=r3.r[10][1];
           break;
       case 'l':
           temp=r3.r[11][1];
           break;
       case 'm':
           temp=r3.r[12][1];
           break;
       case 'n':
           temp=r3.r[13][1];
           break;
       case 'o':
           temp=r3.r[14][1];
           break;
       case 'p':
           temp=r3.r[15][1];
           break;
       case 'q':
           temp=r3.r[16][1];
           break;
       case 'r':
           temp=r3.r[17][1];
           break;
       case 's':
           temp=r3.r[18][1];
           break;
       case 't':
           temp=r3.r[19][1];
           break;
       case 'u':
           temp=r3.r[20][1];
           break;
       case 'v':
           temp=r3.r[21][1];
           break;
       case 'w':
           temp=r3.r[22][1];
           break;
       case 'x':
           temp=r3.r[23][1];
           break;
       case 'y':
           temp=r3.r[24][1];
           break;
       case 'z':
           temp=r3.r[25][1];
           break;
   }
   switch(temp)//Rotor 2
   {
       case 'a':
           temp=r2.r[0][1];
           break;
       case 'b':
           temp=r2.r[1][1];
           break;
       case 'c':
           temp=r2.r[2][1];
           break;
       case 'd':
           temp=r2.r[3][1];
           break;
       case 'e':
           temp=r2.r[4][1];
           break;
       case 'f':
           temp=r2.r[5][1];
           break;
       case 'g':
           temp=r2.r[6][1];
           break;
       case 'h':
           temp=r2.r[7][1];
           break;
       case 'i':
           temp=r2.r[8][1];
           break;
       case 'j':
           temp=r2.r[9][1];
           break;
       case 'k':
           temp=r2.r[10][1];
           break;
       case 'l':
           temp=r2.r[11][1];
           break;
       case 'm':
           temp=r2.r[12][1];
           break;
       case 'n':
           temp=r2.r[13][1];
           break;
       case 'o':
           temp=r2.r[14][1];
           break;
       case 'p':
           temp=r2.r[15][1];
           break;
       case 'q':
           temp=r2.r[16][1];
           break;
       case 'r':
           temp=r2.r[17][1];
           break;
       case 's':
           temp=r2.r[18][1];
           break;
       case 't':
           temp=r2.r[19][1];
           break;
       case 'u':
           temp=r2.r[20][1];
           break;
       case 'v':
           temp=r2.r[21][1];
           break;
       case 'w':
           temp=r2.r[22][1];
           break;
       case 'x':
           temp=r2.r[23][1];
           break;
       case 'y':
           temp=r2.r[24][1];
           break;
       case 'z':
           temp=r2.r[25][1];
           break;
   }
   switch(temp)//Rotor 1
   {
       case 'a':
           temp=r1.r[0][1];
           break;
       case 'b':
           temp=r1.r[1][1];
           break;
       case 'c':
           temp=r1.r[2][1];
           break;
       case 'd':
           temp=r1.r[3][1];
           break;
       case 'e':
           temp=r1.r[4][1];
           break;
       case 'f':
           temp=r1.r[5][1];
           break;
       case 'g':
           temp=r1.r[6][1];
           break;
       case 'h':
           temp=r1.r[7][1];
           break;
       case 'i':
           temp=r1.r[8][1];
           break;
       case 'j':
           temp=r1.r[9][1];
           break;
       case 'k':
           temp=r1.r[10][1];
           break;
       case 'l':
           temp=r1.r[11][1];
           break;
       case 'm':
           temp=r1.r[12][1];
           break;
       case 'n':
           temp=r1.r[13][1];
           break;
       case 'o':
           temp=r1.r[14][1];
           break;
       case 'p':
           temp=r1.r[15][1];
           break;
       case 'q':
           temp=r1.r[16][1];
           break;
       case 'r':
           temp=r1.r[17][1];
           break;
       case 's':
           temp=r1.r[18][1];
           break;
       case 't':
           temp=r1.r[19][1];
           break;
       case 'u':
           temp=r1.r[20][1];
           break;
       case 'v':
           temp=r1.r[21][1];
           break;
       case 'w':
           temp=r1.r[22][1];
           break;
       case 'x':
           temp=r1.r[23][1];
           break;
       case 'y':
           temp=r1.r[24][1];
           break;
       case 'z':
           temp=r1.r[25][1];
           break;
   }
   temp=b[l];

}
```

Comment: I have added expected and actual output in the question

Comment: I don't see any part of the shown code which I would expect to output "The encrypted string is". Is it just me being blind?

Comment: Have you tried running your program line by line in a debugger while monitoring the values of all variables?

Comment: @Yunnosch Concerning your afraided blindness: I searched for "The encrypted string is" using the search function of my browser. I found it three times: in the _Expected output:_, in the _Actual output:_ and in your comment.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] which demonstrates your problem, including that it produces what you give as actual output. It does NOT need to contain all the enigma detials, i.e. you can considerably shorten the shown code. As it is, answering or debugging your code is not cleanly possible and top of that it is annoyingly inconvenient to read your code.

Comment: As you must know already, with `cout<<b;` and `b` being a `char b[500];` means that `b` must contain characters ending with a `'\0` byte. That's how C-style char strings work in C++. Can you point your finger to any line of code in your program that: 1) assigns something to `b`, and 2) makes sure that the last character in `b` is  a `'\0`? This is a trick question. Both appear to be completely missing. Remember the Golden Rule Of Computer Programming: your computer always does what you tell it to do instead of what you want it to do. You never told your computer to put anything into `b`.

Comment: As a beginner you should write no more than 10 lines of code at a time without testing it.

Comment: @stark I will make sure to follow that

Comment: In addition to what has already been pointed out, I have noticed another problem: In the constructor `Rotor::Rotor`, a local variable `r` is declared, which then shadows the member variable `r`. This means that the constructor does not initialize its member variable in any way; it only initializes its local variable. I doubt that this is intended.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik ,as for your question,2)the '\0' will be included automatically right?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel If i remove char from constructor,i get an error saying "Excess elements in scalar initializer"

Comment: @dejavu: If you write the individual characters to the string, then you must also write the terminating null character individually. Nothing is done automatically in this case. Only functions like [strcpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) and [strcat](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) which handle whole strings write a terminating null character automatically.

Comment: What makes you think so? There's very little in C++ that happens "automatically". It is true that there is something called "zero-initialization" that initializes values to 0 when they get constructed. However, this does not happen in this case. You should know that when you declare `int x` variable in a function, for example, it is ***not*** zero-initialized, and every self-respecting C++ compiler will warn you if it detects an attempt to use an uninitialized variable.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel ok i will try that.How do i do that for 2d string?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik oh ok

Comment: @AndreasWenzel yeah,how do i add null char in 2d array?

Comment: @dejavu: Just write `b[l] = '\0';` outside the loop, immediately before the `cout << b;` statement.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel did that,then "the encrypted string is "does not get executed

Comment: The problem in the constructor with the [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) of the member array still exists. In order to fix that, I suggest that you **do** declare another local array, as you do now, and also initialize it as you do now, but give it a different name than your member variable `r`, to prevent the shadowing (i.e. keeping the member array visible). Afterwards, you can copy the local array element by element (in a loop) to the member array `r`, if you want.

Comment: In the constructor, you define the local array as `char r[26][3]`, which is 78 elements, but you only initialize 52 elements. Is that intended? Don't you also want to initialize the last 26 elements?

Comment: @dejavu: In the source code that you posted, I see no line that outputs "the encrypted string is". Are you sure that you posted your latest source code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207891/discussion-between-andreas-wenzel-and-dejavu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting the program to work after an extensive disucssion, we were able to determine that the posted code contains the following bugs:

1. In the constructor `Rotor::Rotor`, a local variable `r` is declared, which then shadows the member variable `r`. This means that the constructor does not initialize its member variable in any way; it only initializes its local variable. This was not intended. Also, the array has 26 * 3 elements, which is 78. However, only 52 of these elements are being initialized.
2. As pointed out by someone else in the comments section, the line `cout << b` causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), because `b` is not initialized (and might not even contain a null terminating character).
3. In the function `logic`, the line `temp=b[l];` should be `b[l]=temp;`.
4. The `Rotor` variables `r1`, `r2`, `r3` are passed to the function `movement` by value, not by reference or pointer. That way, any changes to these variables will not affect the corresponding variables of the function main. However, it was intended that they should be affected.  Therefore, they should be passed by reference or by pointer instead.

In contrast to the function `movement`, it is acceptable to pass the variables `r1`, `r2` and `r3` to the function `logic` by value, because the functions does not modify these variables. However, passing these variables by value is highly inefficient, since these variables each have a size of 78 bytes, so 234 bytes in total. That means that these 234 bytes must be copied every time the function `logic` is called. This copying would not be necessary if these variables were passed by reference or by pointer. Therefore, I would recommend passing these variables by `const` reference or `const` pointer instead. This still ensures that the original variables are not modified, while not requiring a copy to be made.

Also, the excessively long `switch` statements in the function `logic` are unnecessary. The first `switch` statement can be simplified to the following:

`temp = r1.r[temp-'a'][1];`

This trick only works if the characters are stored consecutively in the character set. This is the case with ASCII and most other character sets. However, I believe that the C++ standard itself does not require that the characters be stored consecutively in the character table. But virtually all platforms do this. So it is rather safe to use this trick.

Also, the "REFLECTOR" switch statement can be shortened to the following two lines:

```
const char reflector_map[] = "edhbailcfmogjskrupnwqytzvx";
temp = reflector_map[temp-'a'];
```